# How to fire a single query to fetch the following count of users by month till date in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How to fire a single query to fetch the following count of users by month till date
Index: user (list of all users in a company)

```
users who joined this month (month till date - i.e. in Nov)
users who joined previous month (say Oct)
...
users who joined on second month (say Feb)
users who joined on first month (say Jan)
```

Is there a quick way to fetch all information using a single query, I would like to see a response which contains all information retrieved from a single query?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your issue well, I suggest you use a `date histogram` aggregation alongside with a range query.

`gte` stands for `greater than or equal to` while `lte` stands for `less than or equal to`.

I am first specifying the range I need in this case from `Nov 2020` to `Jan 2020`. Based on this result, I would do an aggregation with interval of `one month`.

I am assuming for each user a document is being created in the index.

I indexed the following data in my index:

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "month-count",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "UPv_l3UBrH4n7Et0xLpD",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "timestamp" : "2020-01-01"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "month-count",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "qPv_l3UBrH4n7Et0-7r9",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "timestamp" : "2020-01-01"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "month-count",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "r_sAmHUBrH4n7Et0e7s-",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "timestamp" : "2020-09-01"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "month-count",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "s_sAmHUBrH4n7Et0gLsh",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "timestamp" : "2020-09-01"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "month-count",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "TfsAmHUBrH4n7Et0nrwS",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "timestamp" : "2020-02-01"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "month-count",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "-vsAmHUBrH4n7Et07Ly-",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "timestamp" : "2020-03-01"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "month-count",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "_vsAmHUBrH4n7Et09LyD",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "timestamp" : "2020-03-01"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "month-count",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "APsAmHUBrH4n7Et0972w",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "timestamp" : "2020-03-01"
    }
  }
]
```

The query which I use:

```
GET month-count/_search
{
"query": {
    "range": {
    "timestamp": {
        "gte": "now-11M/M",
        "lte": "now/M"
    }
    }
}, 
"aggs": {
    "get_Month": {
    "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "month"
    }
    }
}
}
```

The response:

```
    "hits" : [
    {
        "_index" : "month-count",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "UPv_l3UBrH4n7Et0xLpD",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
        "timestamp" : "2020-01-01"
        }
    },
    {
        "_index" : "month-count",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "qPv_l3UBrH4n7Et0-7r9",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
        "timestamp" : "2020-01-01"
        }
    },
    {
        "_index" : "month-count",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "r_sAmHUBrH4n7Et0e7s-",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
        "timestamp" : "2020-09-01"
        }
    },
    {
        "_index" : "month-count",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "s_sAmHUBrH4n7Et0gLsh",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
        "timestamp" : "2020-09-01"
        }
    },
    {
        "_index" : "month-count",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "TfsAmHUBrH4n7Et0nrwS",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
        "timestamp" : "2020-02-01"
        }
    },
    {
        "_index" : "month-count",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "-vsAmHUBrH4n7Et07Ly-",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
        "timestamp" : "2020-03-01"
        }
    },
    {
        "_index" : "month-count",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "_vsAmHUBrH4n7Et09LyD",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
        "timestamp" : "2020-03-01"
        }
    },
    {
        "_index" : "month-count",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "APsAmHUBrH4n7Et0972w",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
        "timestamp" : "2020-03-01"
        }
    }
    ]
},
"aggregations" : {
    "get_Month" : {
    "buckets" : [
        {
        "key_as_string" : "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "key" : 1577836800000,
        "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
        "key_as_string" : "2020-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "key" : 1580515200000,
        "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
        "key_as_string" : "2020-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "key" : 1583020800000,
        "doc_count" : 3
        },
        {
        "key_as_string" : "2020-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "key" : 1585699200000,
        "doc_count" : 0
        },
        {
        "key_as_string" : "2020-05-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "key" : 1588291200000,
        "doc_count" : 0
        },
        {
        "key_as_string" : "2020-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "key" : 1590969600000,
        "doc_count" : 0
        },
        {
        "key_as_string" : "2020-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "key" : 1593561600000,
        "doc_count" : 0
        },
        {
        "key_as_string" : "2020-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "key" : 1596240000000,
        "doc_count" : 0
        },
        {
        "key_as_string" : "2020-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "key" : 1598918400000,
        "doc_count" : 2
        }
    ]
    }
}
```

The `doc_count` is what you need I think.

Let me know if you need help, I will be glad to help you.

Link:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html